# pwa not installable though chrome despite passing the audit

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have a pwa , that passes all instalable tests with the google chrome lighthouse audit tool yet I don't have the option to install the app on chrome, the option add to home screen doesn't show up, despite no errors and passing the instalable test.

[image]

but the option isn't there as you can see below

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you see the option to install on other PWAs? Is it possible that option is disabled on your manged browser?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I did install other pwas before on this browser so that is not the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the [Lighthouse audits](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) are not enough. It is merely one of the many tools that are used to measure the various aspects of your web application, including performance, and accessiblity.

In order to enable your web application as a Progressive Web Application (PWA), you will need to install service workers as well as having HTTPS set up on your web servers. You may refer to the full list of [prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#prerequisites), as well as the other features of [PWAs](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). Do note that

You may follow the following [instructions](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) made available on the official Angular documentation, which provides a step by step guide to enable service workers on your Angular application.